# Rhino Mocks nant error

Tags: .net, nunit, nant, rhino-mocks

Im trying to create a small app using .net 2.0 (client requirements :p), and I have added a reference to the Rhino Mocks dll file, then compiled it using VS2008, all good.

But when I run ant on the project, I get the following error:

[nunit2] SetUp/TearDown Failures:
   [nunit2] 1) DocGen.Test.TestDocumentConfigurator : Could not load file or assembly 'Rhino.Mocks, Version=3.1.0.584, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b3305902db7183f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   [nunit2]    at DocGen.Test.TestDocumentConfigurator..ctor()

Here is my Target:

My solution is like this:

```
Solution-
  DocGen.Test (test project, contains a reference to the DLL)
  DocGenerator (main app, which has the DLL in its \lib directory)
```

I dont really know what that is telling me... It builds in VS2008, but not in nant. Why would this be?

P.S. I also get this error when I run the GUI version of Nunit...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a thought on this, it could be that Im not copying the rhino mocks DLL to the build dir where the DocGen.Test project builds to, ill give this a try, hopefully tonight, and report back.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue! I didnt copy the Rhino Mock Dll to the output dir of the test project...